# Error de impresion con listas y for Java

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas en mi codigo ya que en el primer `system.out println` me arroja correctamente los datos `[36.5, 35.1]`  `[36.4]` y en el segundo me no, me arroja `[36.5, 35.1, 36.4]` y no encuentro alguna fatalla con respecto a esto. Lo que necesito es que me arroje los datos del primer `system.out println`

```
Query qg=mdatabaseGrados.orderByChild("Documento").equalTo(lsd.get(i));
    qg.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            lsg.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Grados=ds.child("Grados").getValue().toString();
                    lsg.add(Grados);
                }        
              System.out.println(lsg);                  
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
System.out.println(lsg);
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Cómo están organizados los datos del Snapshot?

Comment: lo que realizo es un select where document=lsd.get(i), esto me arroja una lista de datos los cuales los almaceno en lsg pero al momento de realizar el llamado del lsg me arroja el valor pero solo de la ultimo

Comment: Muestra una captura de los datos para ver cómo está organizados, no entiendo realmente cuál es el problema. Parece que hay dos objetos que se agregan en el bucle y por eso te lo imprime separados.

Comment: lo eh modificado y ahora me devuelve los datos pero parecen enciptados me arroja ':com.example.temperatura_sag.Extra.TemperaturaBean@69c58e'

Comment: Realmente `@69c58e` no significa que los datos estén encriptados, eso representa la posición en memoria del objeto y ocurre cuando tratas de imprimir un objeto como si fuese una cadena o un primario, si usas cualquiera de los métodos del objeto para mostrar la información verás los datos como los necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'public class TemperaturaBean {
private String Documento;
private String Fecha;
private double Grados;

public String getFecha() {
    return Fecha;
}
public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    Fecha = fecha;
}
public double getGrados() {
    return Grados;
}
public void setGrados(double grados) {
    Grados = grados;
}
public String getDocumento() {
    return Documento;
}
public void setDocumento(String documento) {
    Documento = documento;
}'

'public class Grados_reporte{
    private String Codigo; //DNI
    private List<TemperaturaBean> Valores;

public List<TemperaturaBean> getValores() {
    return Valores;
}

public void setValores(List<TemperaturaBean> valores) {
    Valores = valores;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return Codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    Codigo = codigo;
}'
```

Metodo a ejecutar

```
'public class Listado_grados {
 public Grados_reporte DataToList(DataSnapshot valores){
    Grados_reporte vResponse=new Grados_reporte();
    TemperaturaBean vElement=new TemperaturaBean();
    List<TemperaturaBean> myList=new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for(DataSnapshot ds:valores.getChildren()){
            vElement.setDocumento(ds.child("Documento").getValue().toString());
            vElement.setFecha((ds.child("Fecha").getValue().toString()));
            
   vElement.setGrados(Double.parseDouble(ds.child("Grados").getValue().toString()));
            myList.add(vElement);
        }
        vResponse.setValores(myList);

    }catch (Exception e){
        String vMessage=e.getMessage();
    }
    return vResponse;
}'
```

Y aca lo llamo public ArrayList prueba( int i){

```
    Query qg=mdatabaseGrados.orderByChild("Documento").equalTo(lsd.get(i));
    qg.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            lt.clear();
            /*for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Grados=ds.child("Grados").getValue().toString();
                    //lsg.add(Grados);
                    lt.add(Grados);
                }
    */
               Grados_reporte data = objReporte.DataToList(dataSnapshot);
                for (int a=0; a<data.getValores().size();a++){
                    System.out.println("objeto "+a+" :"+data.getValores().get(a));
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return lt;
}

public void listado(View view){
    for (int a=0;a<lsd.size();a++){
        prueba(a);
         //ArrayList data =  prueba(a);
        //System.out.println("priemro "+data);
    }
}
```

Y lo que me arroja es
I/System.out: objeto 0 :com.example.temperatura_sag.Extra.TemperaturaBean@69c58e
objeto 1 :com.example.temperatura_sag.Extra.TemperaturaBean@69c58e
I/System.out: objeto 0 :com.example.temperatura_sag.Extra.TemperaturaBean@10e91af